# Prove the lower bound $\binom{n}{k-1} \le {n\brace k}$

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, stirling-numbers

A famous and simple lower bounds for [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) is as follows:

$$\binom{n}{k-1} \le {n\brace k}$$

I tried to prove that using the relation $${n\brace k}=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}\left(-1\right)^{j}\left(k-j\right)^n$$

But could not conclude the result.Is it possible to prove this lower bound without using induction? ( If yes then please provide the proof, if no then use induction).

Also why we the lower bound does hold for this example:
$$4=\binom{4}{3}+\binom{5}{3}\color{red}{\nleq}{4\brace 4}+{5\brace 4}=1$$

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, ${4\brace 4}+{5\brace 4} = 1 + 10 = 11$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A property of Stirling Numbers of the Second kind (Combinatorics related)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723185/a-property-of-stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind-combinatorics-related)

Comment: @ Martin R,but is not ${n\brace n-1}=\binom{n}{2}$?

Comment: @ Martin R , the link does not provide a proof without using induction)

Comment: $\binom{n}{k-1} \le {n\brace k}$ is apparently wrong for $k=n > 1$.

Comment: so for what $k$ it's true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $k<n,$ consider a partition like $$\pi =\{B_1,\cdots, B_{k-1},B_k\},$$ such that $B_i=\{a_i\}$ and $1\leq a_1<a_1<\cdots <a_{k-1}\leq n,$ and $B_k=[n]\setminus \{a_1,\cdots ,a_{k-1}\}$ if $k<n,$ then $|B_k|>1$ so it is clear that this way produces an inclusion of $\binom{n}{k-1}$ in the partitions of $[n]$ into $k$ blocks, and the inequality is satisfied. 
The problem with $k=n$ is that you are counting a lot of times($n$ times) the same partition(mainly $1/2/\cdots /n$).

Comment: @ Phicar,what does the left hand side tell us?

Comment: @user715522 It tells us the number of partitions of this form that i wrote down. But because they are not all the partitions possible, then the inequality holds. Unless, clearly, if $n=k.$